# How to create randomized inputs for Criterion benchmarks in Rust

Tags: rust, benchmarking, rust-criterion

I am trying to benchmark the `annotate` routine using the Criterion benchmarking library. The routine is checking a `&[&str]` parameter (2D square string) and returns `Vec<String>` and I suspect that its execution time might depend on the contents of the parameter. Hence, I want to randomize the inputs for a single workload, in this case, workload means width and height of the string parameter (usually width == height).

I noticed that Criterion has `iter_batched` and `iter_batched_ref` methods that take two closures instead of single timed closure, a Setup, and a Routine (timed). Both of them are FnMut so all the captured variables are mutable references (as far as I understand). So I tried to randomize the contents of a `Vec<Vec<u8>>` in the Setup while Routine is only calling my `annotate` function.

```
fn plant_mines<R: Rng + ?Sized>(mfield: &mut Vec<Vec<u8>>, rng: &mut R) {
    mfield.into_iter().flatten().for_each(|x| *x = if rng.gen::<f32>() < MINE_RATE {MINE} else {EMPTY});
}

pub fn benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut rng = rand_pcg::Pcg64Mcg::seed_from_u64(RAND_SEED);
    let bench_params : [(usize, usize); 4] = [
        (3, 3),
        (5, 5),
        (8, 8),
        (16, 16)
    ];

    let dims2str = |d : (usize, usize)| { let (w, h) = d; format!("{:}, {:}", w, h) };

    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("Minefield Benchmark");
    for dims in bench_params.iter() {
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::from_parameter(dims2str(*dims)), dims, |b, (w, h)| {
            let mut mf : Vec<Vec<u8>> = (0..*h).map(|_| iter::repeat(EMPTY).take(*w).collect::<Vec<_>>()).collect();
            let mf_ref = mf.iter().map(|vu8| str::from_utf8(&vu8).unwrap()).collect::<Vec<&str>>();

            b.iter_batched(|| {
                plant_mines(&mut mf, &mut rng);
            }, |_| annotate(&mf_ref), BatchSize::SmallInput);
        });
    }
    group.finish();
}
```

Normally, the Setup function should produce input for the Routine to be used but in this case, I omit them. The `mf_ref` holds a reference vector for `Vec<Vec<u8>>` and I don't want to create/allocate this vector in the timed Routine because otherwise, it will create more noise for the benchmark. Unfortunately, the borrow checker is not happy.

[image]

I tried to create the input vector within the Setup closure but then it cannot return the reference vector to the timed Routine. I tried to understand if either of the `Cell` or `RefCell` can solve the problem but I couldn't grasp them enough to apply in here (if possible). The `Cell` was not possible since `Vec` doesn't implement the `Copy` trait, which I understood.

How can I satisfy the compiler while benchmarking only the `annotate` function and use randomized inputs for each batch of samples?

Comment: I didn't mention but `MINE_RATE`, `MINE`, `EMPTY` and `RAND_SEED` are constants.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the batch mechanism as it is intended, and doing so will solve your conflicting borrow problem. Instead of the benchmarked routine closing over `mf_ref`, you should *create `mf` in the setup closure and return it*. That way, there's no sharing of a mutable reference to `mf`.

```rust
b.iter_batched(|| {
    let mut mf : Vec<Vec<u8>> = (0..*h).map(|_| iter::repeat(EMPTY).take(*w).collect::<Vec<_>>()).collect();
    plant_mines(&mut mf, &mut rng);
    mf
}, |mf| annotate(&mf), BatchSize::SmallInput);
```

Note that this also got rid of `mf_ref`'s transformation to `&str`. This is not possible to implement (easily) here unless the strings are all `&'static str` (which might be possible to do if they're always a string corresponding to MINE or EMPTY, so that you can just have two corresponding string literals); you'll need to redesign your `annotate` so it works on an owned structure or one that refers to only `&'static str`s. (Or you could put it inside the benchmark closure next to `annotate`, but then you're measuring it.)

While of course you shouldn't reshape your code just for the sake of a benchmark, this will probably give you flexibility elsewhere, as long-lasting references are generally inconvenient. I can't advise you on exactly what to do since I don't know what `annotate` does or what the values of `MINE` and `EMPTY` are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, returning `Vec<Vec<u8>>` and passing reference of `mf` to `annotate` doesn't work since the function is expecting `&[&str]` not `&Vec<Vec<u8>>`. I totally agree about not using the batch mechanism as intended. Unfortunately, I cannot change the function signature. Do you have any more idea?